# Facebook login with Codeigniter stopped working suddenly

Tags: facebook, codeigniter

I am using Facebook with Codeigniter and was working fine 
but suddenly stopped working, is facebook changed anything

the facebook function

```
public function takofacebook($page = TRUE, $name = TRUE) {

    if (isset($page) and (($page != TRUE) or ($page != 1)) and isset($name)) {
        $data['page'] = $page;
        $data['name'] = $name;
    }

    $this -> load -> library('fb');
    if (!$this -> fb -> is_connected()) {
        redirect($this -> fb -> login_url(current_url()));
    }

    $fb_user = $this -> fb -> client -> api('/me');

    if (empty($fb_user)) {
        $error = "FACEBOOK LOGIN FAILED - USER US EMPTY. FILE: " . __FILE__ . " LINE: " . __LINE__;
        $this -> session -> set_flashdata('register_error', $error);
    } else {
        $this -> user -> set_facebook_id($fb_user['id']);
        $user = $this -> user -> get_by_facebook();
        if (!empty($user) && !empty($user -> id) && is_numeric($user -> id)) {

            //TODO: Make things a bit more secure here
            //Login & Redirect home

            $this -> _login($user -> id, 'facebook');
            $this -> load -> view('users/redirect_home2', $data);
            return;
        }
    }
    //Go to the registeration page
    $this -> load -> view('users/redirect2', array('method' => 'facebook'));
}

/**
 * Logs user in with facebook
 */

 //tako facebook
public function zangafacebook() {



    $this -> load -> library('fb');
    if (!$this -> fb -> is_connected()) {
        redirect($this -> fb -> login_url(current_url()));
    }

    $fb_user = $this -> fb -> client -> api('/me');

    if (empty($fb_user)) {
        $error = "FACEBOOK LOGIN FAILED - USER US EMPTY. FILE: " . __FILE__ . " LINE: " . __LINE__;
        $this -> session -> set_flashdata('register_error', $error);
    } else {
        $this -> user -> set_facebook_id($fb_user['id']);
        $user = $this -> user -> get_by_facebook();
        if (!empty($user) && !empty($user -> id) && is_numeric($user -> id)) {

            //TODO: Make things a bit more secure here
            //Login & Redirect home

            $this -> _login($user -> id, 'facebook');
            $this -> load -> view('users/redirect_home3');
            return;
        }
    }
    //Go to the registeration page
    $this -> load -> view('users/redirect3', array('method' => 'facebook'));
}
```

Comment: It's obvious that you have your own Facebook library (maybe this library is communicating/extending with the official SDK), make sure you have the latest [SDK version](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk), also try to add the graph api calls `$fb_user = $this -> fb -> client -> api('/me');` to a try catch statement to catch any potential errors.

Answer (score 1):

I tested the official php sdk from Facebook that is on my CodeIgniter site and it works fine. 
Is $fb_user empty? Where is the error? Are you using the official PHP SDK for Facebook? There are a lot of variables to figure out what is going wrong here.
Like ifaour suggests, use the official php sdk here if you are not already: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/tree/master/src

Drop the files in the library directory and call it normally

```
$this -> load -> library('facebook');
```

Then you can get the facebook data like this:

```
$fb_user = $this -> facebook -> api('/me');
```

again I am not sure where your error is so are you missing a parameter here?

$user = $this -> user -> get_by_facebook(**$fb_user['id']**);

This is all I am doing on my site and it is working just fine. This also has the benifit that if Facebook does change anything you just need to download the new SDK and your code should remain unchanged.